# Is there way to view and update an SQLite Database directly (something similar to EasyPHP)

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I am working on a university project, which involves profile and event management using SQLite, due to which i have to write a lot of viewing and debugging code inside the android application which logs the database, so that i can see whether the data is entered correctly or not. Also when i have to insert test data, i have to do it via the application i am developing. Also when i have to clean the database, i have to do it via a functionality in the application, which is again useless except that it allows me to debug.

This is a lot of frustration and useless work. Is there a way, some editor or viewer like Microsofr Access or EasyPHP that allow me to view the database live and enter test data into the Database directly and then update according to the contents of the database.
IDE is eclipse.

Comment: NO need of any quick start guide, just open your database .db file and you can see the data and also run query, more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQLite database there are many Eclipse plugins are available,

In my case I used [MOTODEV](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/) , [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) and [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks! It saves a lot of time!

Answer (score 2):

For browser and modify db directly from  the phone i use SQLite Editor, it's a paid app available on market.
Alternatively you can pull the db file from the emulator/phone with the command:

```
adb pull data/data/yourpackage/databases/youdbname
```

and browse with a Sqlite editor.
If you modify it you can push it back wth the command

```
adb push yourdbname /data/data/yourpackage/databases/yourdbname
```

Answer (score 0):

To edit your database file from a PC you can also use [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/). It allows you to watch at the db with a neat interface and edit data table in a MS Excel style :)