# Android SQLite database storage location and its manipulating tools

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm working on an Android application that stores data in a SQLite database. My question is, where does this database file get stored on the filesystem when you're using an emulator?

And can we modify that database file using some tool ? How ?

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, go to the DDMS perspective, and select the "File Explorer" tab.  Your database will be located under: /data/data//databases.

And here is a handy Eclipse plugin for viewing the database: http://www.cellobject.net/Home.aspx.

Comment: Thanks EJK , Its OK with viewing the database but how can I perform insertion and deletion operation. Is the same plugin is helpful or any other separate plugin available for performing those operations.

Comment: The answer to this question points to several plugins that might do the trick.

Comment: Ooops - forgot the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957351/is-there-way-to-view-and-update-an-sqlite-database-directly-something-similar-t

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way, that doesn't require the installation of nay additional software, is the use of the command lien tool `sqlite3`:

```
$ adb shell
root@android:/ # sqlite3 /data/data/<your-package-name>/databases/your.db
SQLite version 3.7.11 2012-03-20 11:35:50
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite>
sqlite> select * from mytable;
```